# How install ruby with rbenv install 1.9.3-p448 ubuntu 12.04 vagrant box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

can anybody help me how install ruby with rbenv install 1.9.3-p448 ubuntu 12.04 vagrant box
can not install it 
error

```
    Using username "vagrant".
    Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
    Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)
```

`` * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu Jul 18 03:52:48 MSK 2013

  System load:  0.19              Processes:           65
  Usage of /:   15.8% of 7.28GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 30%               IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

Last login: Thu Jul 18 03:45:19 2013 from 10.0.2.2
__rvm_add_to_path: command not found
vagrant@precise32:~$ rbenv  install 1.9.3-p448
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...
Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.gz...
-> http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292.log

Last 10 log lines:
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292/yaml-0.1.4/win32'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292/yaml-0.1.4/win32'
/tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292 ~
~
/tmp/ruby-build.20130718035311.2292 ~

checksum mismatch: ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.gz (file is corrupt)
expected a893cff26bcf351b8975ebf2a63b1023, got fb82dd8806913041373242de9b2212ee

vagrant@precise32:~$ ``

Answer (score 1):

Download the ruby using your browser from ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2 and place it in ~/.rbenv/caches/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2, then run rbenv install 1.9.3-p448

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122668/rbenv-installing-ruby-checksum-mismatch-osx)

Comment: ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2 is not there